# How Do I Populate Text Boxes With Sql Database Data Using One Combo Box

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox

Hey everyone pretty new to SQL Database functions but have been coding in c# for about a year now still not that great at it but I'm getting there!

I'm currently creating a football application and to Edit players and Matches i was wanting to use one drop down combo box to retrieve data from an SQL database which then would populate other text boxes and combo boxes. I've had a go at it myself but don't know where i'm going wrong.

On form load my connection opens i populate my datasets and  i execute this method to populate my combobox

```
private void Navigate()
{
   string showPlayers = "SELECT * From Add_Players";
   SqlCommand cmdData = new SqlCommand(showPlayers, conn);
   SqlDataReader myReader = cmdData.ExecuteReader();

   while (myReader.Read())
   {
      comboEditPlayer.Items.Add(myReader[0]);
   }
   conn.Close();
}
```

After which in the combo box selected index changed method i have this code

```
private void comboEditPlayer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      conn.Open();
      string showPlayers = "SELECT * From Add_Players WHERE Player_ID ='" 
      + comboEditPlayer + "'   ;";
      SqlCommand cmdData = new SqlCommand(showPlayers, conn);
      SqlDataReader myReader = cmdData.ExecuteReader();

      while (myReader.Read())
      {
         comboEditPlayerPos.Items.Add(myReader[1]);
         txtEditPlayerName.Text = myReader[2].ToString();
         txtEditPlayerSecond.Text = myReader[3].ToString();
         comboEditPlayerStatus.Items.Add(myReader[4]);
      }
      conn.Close();
      conn.Dispose();
   } 
   catch (Exception comboFail)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(comboFail.ToString());
   }
}
```

I've been told this code is open and i need to use parameterized queries for preventing hacker attempts which i have started but do not know what Parameter i should be adding to the code i have for this is below

```
private void comboEditPlayer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connectionString =
      ZimbFootball.Properties.Settings.Default.Football2ConnectionString;
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection (connectionString))
   {
      connection.Open();

      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
               "SELECT * From Add_Players WHERE Player_ID =" 
               + comboEditPlayer.SelectedValue + "", connection))
      {
         command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter ("",));
      }
   }
}
```

All help is appreciated and please go easy on me :P

Comment: You should not be running SQL queries from your application, a server side script needs to handle it or else it can easily be exploited.

Comment: I believe as much as it would be good practice for me to do so this application will not be going live thus this way of doing it should be fine but thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Your parameter that should be in your parameterized query is `comboEditPlayer.SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a parameter to the collection with the value of your ComboBox, then execute the query and read back the values from the reader

```
private void comboEditPlayer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string connectionString =
          ZimbFootball.Properties.Settings.Default.Football2ConnectionString;
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection (connectionString))
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                    "SELECT * From Add_Players WHERE Player_ID =@id", connection))
      {
          connection.Open();
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", comboEditPlayer.Text);
          using(SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
              while (myReader.Read())
              {
                    comboEditPlayerPos.Items.Add(myReader[1]);
                    txtEditPlayerName.Text = myReader[2].ToString();
                    txtEditPlayerSecond.Text = myReader[3].ToString();
                    comboEditPlayerStatus.Items.Add(myReader[4]);
              }
          }
       }
 }
```

Comment: Where you have put cmdData.ExecuteReader() do you mean command.ExecuteReader()? cmdData is in the Navigate method tried bringing the string and command into the comboedit but seems to do the same my ID is displayed but once selected doesnt display anything in the text fields

Comment: Yes it's the same to refer back 
string showPlayers = "SELECT * From Add_Players";
SqlCommand cmdData = new SqlCommand(showPlayers, conn);
comboEditPlayer.Items.Add(myReader[0]);

Comment: See my update, in the Navigate method you add the items manually not through the DataSource property, so you cannot use the SelectedValue property, you need SelectedItem or simply the Text property

Comment: So how would i go about doing this is it a simple change to .Text/.SelectedValue or would it be wise for me to change my Navigate code to add items through the DataSource?

Comment: It depends. For an usability point of view, showing the ID instead of the names is not a good option. I would prefer to use the DataSource property, filling a DataTable in the Navigate method and setting the ValueMember to the Player_ID and the DisplayMember to the field name where you store the player name. Then in the selection method you go back to use the SelectedValue property.

Comment: Well truth be they is a bit more work to this project the reason it's an ID is because my requirements states it needs to be a four digit number and the first three letters of a second name so i would actually need an ID for my primary key and a secondary one which increments from 1000 up for example 6453GIG would be Ryan Giggs

Comment: I haven't fully come to understand how i'm going to go about doing this but it's getting there slowly

Comment: I have three adapters which fill DataSets full of my data playerAdapter.Fill(playerDataSet, "Add_Players"); teamAdapter.Fill(teamDataSet, "Add_Teams");
matchAdapter.Fill(matchDataSet, "Add_Matchs");

i presume from here i just need to use the DataSource Property and use something along the lines of dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc];

Comment: Sorry I am bit lost now, why don't you prepare a new question explaining this requirements and putting up some code that tries to resolve them. Perhaps you will get more audience